# Sort an array based on another array's values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How can I sort this array:

```
var list = [
    'forms/buttons',
    'forms/fields',
    'layout/common',
    'layout/sidebar',
    'media/captions',
    'media/galleries',
    'typography/headings',
];
```

based on this order(the part before slash):

```
var needed_order = [
    'typography',
    'forms',
    'media',
    'layout',
];
```

The expected result:

```
// [
//     'typography/headings',
//     'forms/buttons',
//     'forms/fields',
//     'media/captions',
//     'media/galleries',
//     'layout/common',
//     'layout/sidebar',
// ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should help

`Array.prototype.sort` takes a `compareFunction` as an argument to decide the sort order. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> If `compareFunction` is supplied, all non-undefined array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function (all undefined elements are sorted to the end of the array, with no call to `compareFunction`)

```js
var list = [
  'forms/buttons',
  'forms/fields',
  'layout/common',
  'layout/sidebar',
  'media/captions',
  'media/galleries',
  'typography/headings',
];

var needed_order = [
  'typography',
  'forms',
  'media',
  'layout',
];

list.sort((a, b) => needed_order.indexOf(a.split('/')[0]) - needed_order.indexOf(b.split('/')[0]));

console.log(list);
```

Comment: @Luca you can learn more about the Array sort `compareFunction` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: I don't need to learn more about the topic, you should add Information abiut this to your Post ;-)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much for the help. ✌

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by the first appearance in the ˋneeded_orderˋ array:

```
const getPriority = el => needed_order.findIndex(order => el.includes(order));

list.sort((a, b) => getPriority(a) - getPriority(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by the infex of the string which starts with the items to sort.

```js
var list = ['forms/buttons', 'forms/fields', 'layout/common', 'layout/sidebar', 'media/captions', 'media/galleries', 'typography/headings'],
    order = ['typography', 'forms', 'media', 'layout'];

list.sort((a, b) => order.findIndex(v => a.startsWith(v)) - order.findIndex(v => b.startsWith(v)));

console.log(list);
```

A faster version for huge data, could be to store the key index values in a hash table and use it for sorting.

```js
function getS(s) { return s.match(/^[^\/]*/)[0]; }

var list = ['forms/buttons', 'forms/fields', 'layout/common', 'layout/sidebar', 'media/captions', 'media/galleries', 'typography/headings'],
    order = ['typography', 'forms', 'media', 'layout'],
    hash = Object.assign(...order.map((k, v) => ({ [k]: v })));

list.sort((a, b) => hash[getS(a)] - hash[getS(b)]);

console.log(list);
```